# Are there are any volume keyboard shortcuts for the YouTube TV application (www.youtube.com/tv)?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts, mute

I am using the [YouTube TV app](https://www.youtube.com/tv) on a Chrome browser in a Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I have found the keyboard shortcuts for trickplay

```
J: Rewind
K: Play/Pause
L: Fastforward
```

but I cannot find the keyboard shortcuts for controlling the volume (Volume Up/Down, Mute). I tried the ones from YouTube player

```
M: mute
Up/Down arrow: volume up/down
```

but they don't seem to work. Are there any keyboard shortcuts for the volume control of YouTube TV app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering my own question just in case someone find it useful.

There are not any keyboard shortcuts for volume control in the Youtube TV app. Currently the only javascript files that are loaded during a video playback are `tv-player.js`, `live.js`, `csi-tail.js` and `app-prod.js`. The first thought was to check the `tv-player.js` for any shortcuts for volume control, but the only shortcuts were only for navigation.

The `app-prod.js` was the other file which had shortcuts for navigation and trickplay. Next following a snippet from this file

```
    d.qM = function(a) {
    switch (a.keyCode) {
        case 40:
            this.cd("down");
            break;
        case 38:
            this.cd("up");
            break;
        case 37:
            this.cd("left");
            break;
        case 39:
            this.cd("right");
            break;
        case 75:
        case 19:
        case 32:
            this.cd("pause");
            break;
        case 228:
        case 76:
            this.cd("fastforward");
            break;
        case 227:
        case 74:
            this.cd("rewind");
            break;
        case 8:
        case 27:
            this.g.Yq() || L(a)
    }
};
```

Checking the keycodes above with the ones in Webkit's `./Source/WebCore/platform/WindowsKeyboardCodes.h`, the following can be observed

1. The arrow keys are used for navigation (key codes 37, 38, 39 and 40)
2. For play/pause three shortcuts are used (key codes 19, 32 and 75) which are the pause, space and K keyboard keys.
3. For fast forward two shortcuts are used (key codes 76 and 228). 76 is the L keyboard key but 228 couldn't be found in the `./Source/WebCore/platform/WindowsKeyboardCodes.h`. Searching in the other keyboard codes, it was found under `./Source/WebCore/platform/chromium/KeyboardCodes.h` as VKEY_OEM_104.
4. For rewind two shortcuts are used (key codes 74 and 224). 74 is the J keyboard key and again 224 was found in `./Source/WebCore/platform/chromium/KeyboardCodes.h` as VKEY_OEM_103.
5. For quitting video playback two shortcuts were found (key codes 8 and 27) which are the back and escape keyboard keys.
6. No shortcuts for volume control were found.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, "M" works to mute/unmute, for me... this may be new.

Answer (score -1):

Use shift with up and down arrows to control the volume on YouTube TV. It works for me.